# Set up levels of details for custom basemaps using ArcGIS Javascript API 3.17

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to implement layers of details (LODs) on a few custom basemaps using the ArcGIS Javascript API 3.17. One is for less detail, and the other two used for more detail, but covering different zones. I'm having issues, and the page isn't loading however (for Firefox and IE). Can anyone see anything I'm not? Note, that I've used some sample services here. Additionally, I've added some dynamic feature layers in my real implementation, that I've not included here.

```
var map;
var extent;
var baseMapLayerPPT;
var baseMapLayerPoly;
var customLods = [];
var loadCount = 0;

require([
  "esri/geometry/Extent","esri/map", "esri/dijit/Search", "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer","esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/InfoTemplate", "dojo/domReady!"
], function (Extent, Map, Search, DynamicMapServiceLayer, FeatureLayer, InfoTemplate) {

  baseMapLayerPoly = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer", {
    displayLevels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
  });

  baseMapLayerPoly.on("load", addLods);

  baseMapLayerPPT = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer", {
    displayLevels: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ],
    //opacity : 0.75
  });

  extent = new esri.geometry.Extent({
    "xmin":-91070.37,"ymin":7988806.64,"xmax":301214.62,"ymax":8227343.05,
    "spatialReference":{"wkid":3297}
  });

  // popuplate an array with zoom levels
  function addLods(evt) {
    customLods = customLods.concat(evt.layer.tileInfo.lods);
    loadCount++;
    if (loadCount === 2) {
      initMap();
    }
  }

  // create the map and use the custom zoom levels
  function initMap() {
    map = new Map("mapDiv", {
      center: [-150, -17],
      zoom: 9,
      lods : customLods
    });
    map.on("extent-change", changeScale);
    map.addLayers([baseMapLayerPoly,baseMapLayerPPT);
  }

  //Report which layer is being shown
  function changeScale(evt) {
    dom.byId("scale").innerHTML = "Level: <i>" + evt.lod.level;
    if (evt.lod.level < 11) {
      dom.byId("visibleLayer").innerHTML = "Layer: <i>Imagery</i>";
    } else if (evt.lod.level == 11) {
      // both layers are loaded
      dom.byId("visibleLayer").innerHTML = "<i>Both layers currently visible</i>";
    } else {
      dom.byId("visibleLayer").innerHTML = "Layer: <i>Streets</i>";
    }
  }


});
```

Comment: I think you code is not complete, the function `addLods` is called only once, so the `initMap` wont be called. Please edit with correct code.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for it...

Comment: Add complete code atleast.. along with HTML and all..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I observed few errors in above code -

1. In require `ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer` was not mentioned.
2. `initMap();` was not triggering by this line -  `baseMapLayerPoly.on("load", addLods);`
3. Closing backet is missing `map.addLayers([baseMapLayerPoly,baseMapLayerPPT);`
4. `lods : customLods` is causing another error
5. `map.on("extent-change", changeScale);` was causing error because html was not there...

After correcting above issues **below is the working code:-**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.17/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #map {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.17/"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        var extent;
        var baseMapLayerPPT;
        var baseMapLayerPoly;
        var customLods = [];
        var loadCount = 0;

        require([
                    "esri/geometry/Extent", "esri/map", "esri/dijit/Search", "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer", "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/InfoTemplate", "dojo/domReady!"
                ], function(Extent, Map, Search, ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer, DynamicMapServiceLayer, FeatureLayer, InfoTemplate) {

                    baseMapLayerPoly = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer", {
                        displayLevels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
                    });

                    baseMapLayerPoly.on("load", addLods);

                    baseMapLayerPPT = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer", {
                        displayLevels: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                        //opacity : 0.75
                    });
                    initMap();
                    extent = new Extent({
                        "xmin": -91070.37,
                        "ymin": 7988806.64,
                        "xmax": 301214.62,
                        "ymax": 8227343.05,
                        "spatialReference": {
                            "wkid": 3297
                        }
                    });

                    // popuplate an array with zoom levels
                    function addLods(evt) {
                        customLods = customLods.concat(evt.layer.tileInfo.lods);
                        loadCount++;
                        if (loadCount === 2) {
                            initMap();
                        }
                    }

                    // create the map and use the custom zoom levels
                    function initMap() {
                        map = new Map("map", {
                            center: [-150, -17],
                            zoom: 9//,
                            //lods: customLods
                        });
                        //map.on("extent-change", changeScale);
                        map.addLayers([baseMapLayerPoly, baseMapLayerPPT]);
                        }

                        //Report which layer is being shown
                        function changeScale(evt) {
                            dom.byId("scale").innerHTML = "Level: <i>" + evt.lod.level;
                            if (evt.lod.level < 11) {
                                dom.byId("visibleLayer").innerHTML = "Layer: <i>Imagery</i>";
                            } else if (evt.lod.level == 11) {
                                // both layers are loaded
                                dom.byId("visibleLayer").innerHTML = "<i>Both layers currently visible</i>";
                            } else {
                                dom.byId("visibleLayer").innerHTML = "Layer: <i>Streets</i>";
                            }
                        }


                    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Hoping this will help you :)**

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code you have shared. As Vikas has pointed out, there are a few syntax errors. The map automatically, updates the zoomlevels, from the first layer/basemap it loads, you need not update it explicitly. In case you need it to be different than the layer you can get the **LOD from the layer** like you are trying or create it in javascript like below. you can easily get the details for the `LOD` from the service page.

```
var tilelods = [
   {
    "level": 0,
    "resolution": 156543.03392800014,
    "scale": 5.91657527591555E8
   },
   {
    "level": 1,
    "resolution": 78271.51696399994,
    "scale": 2.95828763795777E8
   },
   {
    "level": 2,
    "resolution": 39135.75848200009,
    "scale": 1.47914381897889E8
   },
   .
   .
   .
   {
    "level": 15,
    "resolution": 4.77731426794937,
    "scale": 18055.954822
   }
];
map = new Map("mapDiv", {
  center: [-150, -17],
  zoom: 9,
  lods : tilelods
});
```

Make sure you are not repeating the levels/lods.

As per the code shared you are just adding ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer to the map. Its not a Basemap. If you need a base map you need to add it as shown in this snippet.

```js
var map;
        require(["esri/geometry/Extent", "esri/map", "esri/dijit/Basemap", "esri/dijit/BasemapLayer", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/InfoTemplate", "dojo/domReady!"], 
                function(Extent, Map, Basemap, BasemapLayer, FeatureLayer, InfoTemplate) {

          var baseMap = new Basemap({
              id: "CustomBaseMap",
              layers : [
                  new BasemapLayer({ url : "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer",
                                    displayLevels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] }),
                  new BasemapLayer({ url : "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer",
                                    displayLevels: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15] })             
              ]
          });
          
          map = new Map("map", { 
            center: [-150, -17],
            zoom: 9//,
          });
          map.setBasemap(baseMap)
          

      });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.17/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
        html,
        body,
        #map {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.17/"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```